Error occurred when compiling Knowhere independently and then integrating it into the vector database
This is the original directory:
out|
-- include
-- lib64

Then, I was trying to move the files into these two directory:
/internal/core/output/include
/internal/core/output/lib64

However, this error occurred:
/install/milvus/internal/core/src/config/ConfigKnowhere.cpp:23:10: fatal error: knowhere/comp/knowhere_config.h: No such file or directory
23 | #include "knowhere/comp/knowhere_config.h"
/install/milvus/cmake_build/thirdparty/milvus-storage/milvus-storage-src/cpp/test/test_util.cpp:15:10: fatal error: test_util.h: No such file or directory
15 | #include "test_util.h"

This is the directory structure of compiled Knowhere results:
├── include
│   └── knowhere
│   ├── binaryset.h
│   ├── bitsetview.h
│   ├── bitsetview_idselector.h
│   ├── cluster
│   │   ├── cluster_factory.h
│   │   ├── cluster.h
│   │   └── cluster_node.h
│   ├── comp
│   │   ├── blocking_queue.h
│   │   ├── brute_force.h
│   │   ├── index_param.h
│   │   ├── knowhere_check.h
│   │   ├── knowhere_config.h
│   │   ├── local_file_manager.h
│   │   ├── materialized_view.h
│   │   ├── task.h
│   │   ├── thread_pool.h
│   │   └── time_recorder.h
│   ├── config.h
│   ├── dataset.h
│   ├── expected.h
│   ├── feder
│   │   ├── DiskANN.h
│   │   ├── HNSW.h
│   │   └── IVFFlat.h
│   ├── file_manager.h
│   ├── heap.h
│   ├── index
│   │   ├── index_factory.h
│   │   ├── index.h
│   │   ├── index_node_data_mock_wrapper.h
│   │   ├── index_node.h
│   │   ├── index_node_thread_pool_wrapper.h
│   │   └── index_table.h
│   ├── log.h
│   ├── object.h
│   ├── operands.h
│   ├── prometheus_client.h
│   ├── range_util.h
│   ├── sparse_utils.h
│   ├── tracer.h
│   ├── utils.h
│   └── version.h
└── lib64
└── libknowhere.so

I hope I have given a clear picture of the issue and sets the stage for a more in-depth discussion on how to resolve it. If anyone has dealt with similar issues or has insights into this, please chime in with your suggestions or solutions!
I'm looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you in advance for your help!

Looks like you'll need to edit this file: https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus/blob/master/internal/core/thirdparty/knowhere/CMakeLists.txt to point to your local directory and not the git repo
